# Error while getting the middle element of a list in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, element

First, I am completely new to Haskell, so sorry for the question in advance, as it might look kind of simple, but still I get this error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for middle :: [a] -> a
      at myFile.lhs:18:12
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a] (bound at myFile.lhs:20:12)
  x :: a (bound at myFile.lhs:20:10)
  middle :: [a] -> a
    (bound at myFile.lhs:19:2)
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `x'
In the first argument of `div', namely `x !! length xs'
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

While trying to load:

```
>middle :: [a] -> a
>middle [] = []
>middle (x:xs) = if (l `mod` 2 == 0) then xs !! (l`div` 2) - 1 else x !! l `div` 2
    where l = length xs
```

If something is vague or unclear, please comment.

**EDIT**
Because of the use of *div* I get:

```
Error:     No instance for (Integral a) arising from a use of `div'
Possible fix:
  add (Integral a) to the context of
    the type signature for middle :: [a] -> a
In the expression: xs !! l `div` 2
In the expression:
  if (l `mod` 2 == 0) then xs !! (l `div` 2) - 1 else xs !! l `div` 2
In an equation for `middle':
    middle (x : xs)
      = if (l `mod` 2 == 0) then
            xs !! (l `div` 2) - 1
        else
            xs !! l `div` 2
      where
          l = length xs
```

Comment: I think the div problem is that you may need extra parentheses. It's possible that you may be trying to compute div (x !! l) 2 instead of x !! (div l 2). The former would require the element type to be Integral; the latter merely requires Int to be Integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `x` is just an element, not a list. So, using `x !! anything` is a type error. Did you mean `xs !! anything` instead?

Further,

```
middle [] = []
```

is wrong since you must return an element, not a list. Since there is no middle element, we can only return bottom, e.g.

```
middle [] = error "middle: empty list"
```

The above makes the function a partial one, i.e. if in a larger program you call the function with an empty list, the program will crash.

If you want to forbid that, you can change the type to `Maybe`:

```
middle :: [a] -> Maybe a
middle []     = Nothing
middle (x:xs) = Just (.....)
```

Comment: also,when [a]->a is Num and *div* needs Integral, how can I fix it. I have edited my question

Comment: @user4325010 Probably you lack parentheses, try ``xs !! (l `div` 2)``